# Setting cookies for dynamic classes or IDs

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this little part of code..

```
$("#custom_background span").click(function () {
    $("#account ,.minwidth_IE ,.main .main-head ,#fa_toolbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom").addClass($(this).attr("id"));

    $("#vbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom bg11 bg21 bg31 bg41 bg51 bg71 bg81").addClass($(this).attr("id")+ (+1));

    $("#tbar").removeClass("bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4 bg5 bg7 bg8 bg_custom bg12 bg22 bg32 bg42 bg52 bg72 bg82").addClass($(this).attr("id")+ (+2));

    my_setcookie("custom_background", $(this).attr("id")+ (''), true);
});
```

I'm sure i have to write another my_setcookie.. but i don't know how. If i set for each element, it will bug my forum. The question is, how to set cookie for #tbar, #vbar and #account, miniwidth_IE etc.. ? Thank you very much!

Comment: How much do you want to save in the cookies X_X This construct looks scarry

Comment: You can use Jquery Cookie plugin! And it would work like, `$.cookie("custom_background", $(this).attr("id"))`

Comment: I want very much.. this is for a theme changer (to change the theme), and if i change the page.. the theme dissapears and you have to choose it again. :D